# Is this partial differential equation on topic for Mathoverflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic

I came across this differential equation. I'm not sure if it's research level, but I think it might be:

$$u\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(u\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\right) + v\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(v\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right)=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v^2}$$

> Is something like this on topic/research level?

I've been trying to find out if anyone has solved this before so that I could understand their solution but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: A PDE is not a question, and only questions can be on topic. What do you want to ask about this PDE?

Comment: I would say: ask it first in math.se if you are not familiar with the PDE literature.  Of course, when you ask there you will need to include more than just a random problem statement.

Comment: @DenisNardin I wanted to ask about this PDE's solutions

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Okay I did that

Comment: @geocalc33 Good luck with math.SE, but in any case, what do you want to know about the solutions? I am very far from an expert in PDE, but my understanding is that an analytic expression for the solutions is pretty much never an option. Often people ask questions about existence, regularity, dimension of the space of solutions etc.